# Error reloading cmake project-"Could NOT find Boost"

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to Cmake and boost. I am now working on a open source program and want to reload cmake project.

I've installed boost 1.74.0 with brew(MacOS), and I checked the directory "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.74.0", found the lib directory "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.74.0/lib" has .a and .dylib files as expected.
Here are part of the files in lib directory:

```
-r--r--r--   1 lulijun  staff   9550840  8 11  2020 libboost_regex-mt.a
-r--r--r--   1 lulijun  staff   1004840  6 21 11:20 libboost_regex-mt.dylib
-r--r--r--   1 lulijun  staff   9550840  8 11  2020 libboost_regex.a
-r--r--r--   1 lulijun  staff   1004648  6 21 11:20 libboost_regex.dylib
```

But When I try to reload cmake project, the following question arises

```
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: thread regex system filesystem date_time program_options (found /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.74.0"))



  CMake Error at src/service/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_executable):
  Target "palo_be" links to target "Boost::regex" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Here is my boost config in cmake file:

```
# Set Boost
set(Boost_DEBUG FALSE)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.74.0)
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE OFF)

SET(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost)


find_package(Boost 1.74.0 COMPONENTS thread regex system filesystem date_time program_options)
```

Is there anything I mised? How can I resolve this problem?

Here is the full message with Boost_DEUBUG = TRUE, there are too many CMake Error but they look like the same, so I just copy 2 of them.

```
-- GLIBC_COMPATIBILITY is ON
-- Build type is DEBUG
-- Build target arch is x86_64
-- make test: ON
-- defined PIC_LIB_PATH
-- build gensrc if necessary
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C script
/Users/lulijun/git/github/incubator-doris/gensrc/script/gen_build_version.sh
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C proto
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C thrift
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
-- Found Boost 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.74.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET COMPONENTS thread;regex;system;filesystem;date_time;program_options
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_headers 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.74.0
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_thread 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_thread 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is clang-darwin100 (AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044)
-- Scanning /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0/libboost_thread-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0/libboost_thread-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0/libboost_thread-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mt.a
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_regex 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_regex 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is clang-darwin100 (AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044)
-- Scanning /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mt.a
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex.a
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_system 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_system 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is clang-darwin100 (AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044)
-- Scanning /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0/libboost_system-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0/libboost_system-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_system-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0/libboost_system-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_system-mt.a
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0/libboost_system-variant-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_system.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.74.0/libboost_system-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_system.a
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_filesystem 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_filesystem 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is clang-darwin100 (AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044)
-- Scanning /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mt.a
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem.a
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_date_time 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_date_time 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is clang-darwin100 (AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044)
-- Scanning /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.74.0/libboost_date_time-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.74.0/libboost_date_time-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_date_time-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.74.0/libboost_date_time-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_date_time-mt.a
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.74.0/libboost_date_time-variant-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_date_time.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_date_time-1.74.0/libboost_date_time-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_date_time.a
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_program_options 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_program_options 1.74.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is clang-darwin100 (AppleClang 10.0.0.10001044)
-- Scanning /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0/libboost_program_options-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0/libboost_program_options-variant-mt-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options-mt.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0/libboost_program_options-variant-mt-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options-mt.a
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0/libboost_program_options-variant-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options.dylib
--   Including /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0/libboost_program_options-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_program_options.a
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: thread regex system filesystem date_time program_options (found /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.74.0"))
-- Compiler Flags:  -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++17 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -Wno-deprecated -Wno-vla -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBRPC_ENABLE_CPU_PROFILER -DBOOST_UUID_RANDOM_PROVIDER_FORCE_POSIX=1 -msse4.2  -Wno-attributes -DS2_USE_GFLAGS -DS2_USE_GLOG -DDORIS_WITH_MYSQL -faligned-new  -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -ggdb3 -O0 -gdwarf-2
-- Some symbols from glibc will be replaced for compatibility
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at src/service/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_executable):
  Target "palo_be" links to target "Boost::regex" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at src/service/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_executable):
  Target "palo_be" links to target "Boost::system" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Comment: Please set `Boost_DEBUG` to TRUE and rerun CMake. That should give you a better clue what is going on.

Comment: Please paste the full CMake output message.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, I set the Boost_DEBUG to TRUE, and found it does scan the lib directory and find some files about thread and regex and so on, but the next step the "Could NOT find Boost" error still comes up. 
The full message is too long, so I pasted it in the body of the question

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin  Thank u for your time, The full message is too long, so I pasted it in the body of the question.

Comment: Seems it's the problem in link part, not the find_package part you pasted, try to replace with boost_thread in linkage

Comment: my guess would be that boost is compiled for a different architecture(s) than you are trying to currently compile for

Comment: If I read the boost cmake code correctly, every component should store the reason why none of its variants were selected. Can you print the contents of `${boost_regex_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE}`?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Do u mean change the "find_package" command to add a default prefix "boost_" to every module?  
find_package(Boost 1.74.0 COMPONENTS boost_thread boost_regex boost_system boost_filesystem boost_date_time boost_program_options)
But it seems like the "boost_" is the default prefix of every module, if i add change thread to boost_thread, it will try to find boost_boost_thread:  BoostConfig: find_package(boost_boost_thread 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)

Comment: I mean the linkage part:`target_link_libraries`, not the change you applied.

Comment: @Botje I pasted the full message with Boost_DEBUG=TRUE, but it does not have the reason of why none of its variants were selected. Is there any way to get the reason?

Comment: As I said, the contents of that variable should explain why each variant was rejected

Comment: @Botje  Thank u for your time. Here is the rejected message, I'm not familiar with this information. Is this a permission issue? 
-- info = No suitable build variant has been found.
The following variants have been tried and rejected:
* libboost_regex-mt.dylib (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)
* libboost_regex-mt.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)
* libboost_regex.dylib (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)
* libboost_regex.a (shared runtime, Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON)

Answer (score 2):

The final comment reveals your problem: you (or your system) have selected a combination of flags for Boost that make it impossible to find the right library:

- `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`: only selects the .a files to include in your program
- `Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME`: only selects files that are "linked statically to the C++ runtime". These have an "s" tag in their variant, but are not present on your system.

Turn off at least `Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME`, and then it is up to you whether you want to dynamically link with Boost or not.